# 1.9 upgrade: can not parse dojoType widgets

Tags: dojo

I'm upgrading from 1.8.3 to 1.9.1. Build went smoothly, but page load has issues... While loading, dojo can not parse any of the dojoType widgets in the HTML template. There are other attach points for plain DOM nodes and those attach points are accessible, but dojoType nodes' attach points are undefined. I scanned through the 1.9 changes [here](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/releasenotes/1.9) without much luck. Anyone had a similar experience?

Here is the stack trace:

```
myproj/views/_Home.js  <---- crashes here while attempting to 
                             read a widget's attach point in the template
dijit/_WidgetBase.js: line 541
dojo/_base/declare.js: line 203
dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin.js: line 107
dojo/_base/declare.js: line 203
myproj/views/_Home.js: line 26 <--- Page loads with this widget... This is a 
                                    templated widget, and this line is the     
                                    this.inherited(arguments) of startup().
```

Dojo Loading in head:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/tara/config.js?1384202981691"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $appBaseUri = 'http://cms.mydemo.com';
        var dojoConfig = {
            parseOnLoad: false,
            dojoBlankHtmlUrl: "/static/cms/blank.html",
            uploaderPath: "/static/nocache/uploader.swf",
            locale: "en-gb",
            cacheBust: "1384202981691",
            debugAtAllCosts: true,
            isDebug: true,
            packages: $appconfig.devMode.packages               
        }
    </script>       
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/lib/dojo/dojo/dojo.js?1384202981691"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("myapp._dojo");
        dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
            dojo.require("myapp._base");
            dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
                dojo.require("cms.models._all");
                dojo.require("cms._base");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The template being rendered, home.html below. All other attachpoints are accessible, but not 'mainStack' and 'windows'.

```
<div class="container" title="">
    <div dojoAttachPoint="header">
    <div dojoAttachPoint="headerInner">
        <div dojoAttachPoint="topNavNode">
        </div>
        <div dojoAttachPoint="mainDetails"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div dojoAttachPoint="mainStack" dojoType="dijit.layout.StackContainer"></div>
</div>
<div dojoAttachPoint="windows" dojoType="myapp.layout.WindowContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Without seeing the HTML in question, this is very difficult to answer.

Comment: i've added the html and dojo loading in <head>.

Comment: You're going to have to give more detail. How are you trying to access those attach points? Show some code. What is the actual error? "Crashes" is not an error.

Comment: I resolved the issue for this question. The issue laid in our module that overwrites dijit/_Templated.js and it needed to adapt to the changes in 1.9.1, namely deprecation of _Templated going forward and introduction of _AttachMixin.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather vague, but I'm going to go out on a limb here and assume you simply need to switch your `dojoType` attributes with `data-dojo-type` instead...similarly for attach points and such:

```
<div id="homeView" data-dojo-type="myproj/views/_Home" data-dojo-props="someProp:'someValue'"></div>
```

And in your widget's template:

```
<div>
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="someAttachPoint">...</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: no, data-dojo-type etc won't help. there are other dataAttachPoints for plain HTML nodes and they are accessible.